# The Dangers of Solving SQL0666 Errors With QUERYTIMEOUT=0

Tags: ms-access, db2, odbc, ms-access-2007, db2-400

I'm using Microsoft Access 2007 with an IBM AS400 DB2 SQL v6r1 server. Recently I began expanding my DB2 experience by converting some of my more complicated Access queries to the Pass-Through type. The increase in query speed is amazing but expected, especially in our larger tables, some with 20,000,000+ rows.

As one might expect with Access + DB2, I've been running into the SQL0666 error. Or at least...I expect it now because I've run into it a lot. I've applied self-help and solved the issue by increasing the 'ODBC Timeout' property of the Pass-Through queries. I find what seems like a logically safe value by increasing it until the query works, and then doubling it.

Whatever way Access computes its estimate of a query's duration, it seems grossly out of proportion with reality. If I copy/paste such a query into the IBM iNavigator SQL window and run it there, it takes a fraction of the time, sometimes as much as 1/10th what Access thinks it should take.

Yesterday I stumbled across the following webpage, which describes steps to remove the query timeout problem altogether. I found it adds 'QUERYTIMEOUT=0' to the DSN, and this seems like a permanent cure to the SQL0666 error.

https://kb.rfgen.com/kb/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=107

But...

Isn't this dangerous..?

Could a runaway query soak the server until everyone screams or it crashes..?

Is there another deeper timeout limit to protect against runaway processes..?

I'm tempted to add it to all my queries, but as a concerned nerd, I'm hesitant about it.

Comment: On the i-server side, there is a separate system wide query-time limit. see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzakz/rzakzqqrytimlmt.htm  .  Maybe you should invest in optimising the queries ... ?

Comment: And...I'm glad I asked. The value 'Database Query Time Limit' is set to 'No Maximum'. Thank you for pointing it out. As for optimizing the queries, I do what my knowledge allows. I do understanding some facets of optimization are handled automatically by the server, such as handling subqueries as joins (but then I try to do this anyways), but more than that I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Access that performs the query run time estimation -- it's the Db2 for iSeries optimizer itself.

There are several levels where you can set the timeout, as explained in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1017615), but the ODBC setting overrides them all.

And you are right in your reservations: the purpose of the timeout is precisely to prevent "runaway" queries from consuming too many resources. There is probably very little risk of crashing the server using modern hardware, but performance of concurrent users' queries may definitely suffer.

You may want to speak with your server administrator to determine what the appropriate maximum timeout value might be in your environment and use it in your data source definition.

[Manual reference.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/xqrygovr.htm)

Comment: I am the server administrator...barely, lol. But we get mondo tech support from the vendor of the big software package that we use, so when I do need support beyond what the average user might need, they're usually willing to help. Thank you for the links.

Comment: If you are worried about the impact of your queries on more general system performance (or indeed you just want to make them go as fast as possible), I would advise having a look at the brilliant Visual Explain functionality (in IBM i Navigator Run SQL Scripts).

Comment: @MandyShaw ... Holy cow..!! I use the Run SQL Scripts window regularly, but I never fiddled with the Visual Explain. I can see how it could be super handy for figuring out where a complicated query might be log-jamming. Thanks!